# Confused by order of execution with a print function call as a function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run

```
def func(one,two):
    print(one)
    two

func("1",print("hi"))
func("2",print("hello"))
```

in an interpreter session, I get the output:

```
hi
1
hello
2
```

Is the code not supposed to run from top to bottom? The output I expected is:

```
1
hi
2
hello
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `print` statement returns `None`, which you are passing to your function as the second argument.

What happens when you call `func("1", print("hi"))` is that `print("hi")` will be executed, so you will see `hi` first.
After that, `func("1", None)` is called, which will do

```
print("1")
None
```

and the only output you will see from that is `1`, because the statement

```
None
```

does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

When you call a function the arguments are first evaluated. Therefore "hi" is already printed. When the arguments are evaluated, they are passed to the function and the function is called which prints "1".